# How can I import and export more than 1 number in .txt?

Tags: c

First program , I input a , b ,c ,d ,e

```
#include"stdio.h"
#include"stdlib.h"

int main(){
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("abcde","w");
    if(f==NULL){
        printf("Error");
        exit(0);
    }
    float a,b,c,d,e;
    a=5;
    b=6;
    c=7;
    d=8;
    e=9;
    fprintf(f,"%f",a);
    fprintf(f,"%f",b);
    fprintf(f,"%f",c);
    fprintf(f,"%f",d);
    fprintf(f,"%f",e);
    fprintf(f,"%f",f);
    fclose(f);
}
```

Then sencond program , I want output a ,b ,c ,d ,e . But it just output a . How can I output all a, b, c ,d ,e

```
#include"stdio.h"
#include"stdlib.h"

int main(){
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("abcde","r");
    if(f==NULL){
        printf("Error");
        exit(0);
    }
    float a,b,c,d,e;
    fscanf(f,"%f",&a);
    fscanf(f,"%f",&b);
    fscanf(f,"%f",&c);
    fscanf(f,"%f",&d);
    fscanf(f,"%f",&e);
    printf("%f  %f  %f  %f  %f",a,b,c,d,e);
    fclose(f);
}
```

You can see my img . in txt file it has all data
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write to the file, there is nothing separating each number.  So when it reads a `float` is stops when it reaches a second decimal point.

When writing to the file, put a space or newline between each number:

```
fprintf(f,"%f ",a);
fprintf(f,"%f ",b);
fprintf(f,"%f ",c);
fprintf(f,"%f ",d);
fprintf(f,"%f ",e);
fprintf(f,"%f ",f);
```

Then when you read the number back in, the space acts as a separator.

Comment: hoooooo , i can do it this bug took me a lot of time

Comment: @NgocAnh Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Comment: thanks you veryyyyyyyyyyy muchhhhhhhhhhhh @dbush